# Main form minimized while other form maximized

Tags: delphi, vcl

I'm wondering how you can have your main form, say Form1, minimize itself while keeping Form2 maximized. Is there an easy method to perform this task within the VCL? I'd prefer if each form could function independent from one another.

Comment: Override CreateParams for secondary forms to set Params.WndParent to 0. Searching on a variation of the names here, you'll find plenty of related source.

Comment: Don't be surprised though, when you alt+tab to one of your forms the others are left behind. This is *functioning independently*.

Comment: Hi thanks for that. Form2 is doing what I wanted now but there is some weird things happening when Applcation.Minimize is called. When I click the icon in taskbar the main form is not restored. Any idea about why this is happening?

Comment: No, no repro with a simple project. In any case you shouldn't be using Application.Minimize, *Application* is designed to make behave all forms coordinated, not to function independently.